# How to properly run multiple tasks using one worker in heroku and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, scheduled-tasks, rake

I'm trying to run many (over 20) tasks in Heroku every minute simultaneously, but I'm pretty sure I'm not doing it correctly. I'm currently using the Standard-1X dynos
with 512 MB RAM. I'm pretty sure I should be able to achieve my goal without having to upgrade heroku. My solution kind of works, but it uses up a lot of my memory and it's not running all tasks simultaneously. Can someone help me come up with a better solution?

Here is my Rakefile:

```
Rails.application.load_tasks

task :update_exchanges_1 => :environment do
 until 2 < 1 do
  Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:gdax'].execute
  Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:gemini'].execute
  Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:bitstamp'].execute
  Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:bitflyer'].execute
  Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:okex'].execute
  Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:cex'].execute
  sleep(60.seconds)
 end
end

task :update_exchanges_2 => :environment do
  until 2 < 1 do
   Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:bitfinex'].execute
   Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:bittrex'].execute
   Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:hitbtc'].execute
   Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:poloniex'].execute
   Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:kraken'].execute
   Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:binance'].execute
   Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:bithumb'].execute
   sleep(60.seconds)
 end
end

task :update_exchanges_3 => :environment do
  until 2 < 1 do
    Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:gateio'].execute
    Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:idex'].execute
    Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:bitbank'].execute
    Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:zb'].execute
    Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:bibox'].execute
    Rake::Task['exchange_markets_update:ethfinex'].execute
    sleep(60.seconds)
  end
 end
```

So basically, each task is called indefinitely and is used to call multiple external API's that are used to update my database. Each exchange_markets_update task takes about 10-15 secs.

Here is my Procfile (I'm using foreman gem so I can run processes within a process):

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.workers
```

Here is my Profile.workers:

```
dj_worker: bundle exec rake update_exchanges_1
dj_worker: bundle exec rake update_exchanges_2
dj_worker: bundle exec rake update_exchanges_3
```

It is also important to note that my worker crashes after some time. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does wrapping each `execute` call in a `Thread.new {}` block work?

Comment: What execute call?

Comment: Each of the lines where you call `execute`. But let me ask. Are you trying to the `update_exchanges` tasks to run in parallel? or the `exchange_markets_update` ones?

Comment: the exchange_markets_update ones